# Configuring an Ext.data.XmlStore to obtain custom tags from response

Tags: extjs, tags, xmlstore

Hi I have the following xml returned from the server:
Code:

[link text](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?115581-Configuring-an-XmlStore-based-on-an-Xml-response)

I couldn''t seem to get the xml store configuration right. Especially, I want to be able to obtain the custom tags: name, intra and referrals which are properties of the result set returned.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (replace test.xml with your xml source)

```
    // create the Data Store
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    // load using HTTP
    url: 'test.xml',
    // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
           // records will have an "customer" tag
           record: 'customer',
       }, ['id','field1', 'field2', 'field3'])
});

// create the grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {header: "id", width: 120, dataIndex: 'id', sortable: true},
        {header: "field1", width: 180, dataIndex: 'field1', sortable: true},
        {header: "field2", width: 115, dataIndex: 'field2', sortable: true},
        {header: "field3", width: 100, dataIndex: 'field3', sortable: true}
    ],
    renderTo:'example-grid',
    width:540,
    height:200
});
store.load();
```

in order to obtain the tags: name, intra and referrals i used Ext.DomQuery which enables you to parse to xml (try it for  intra and referrals )

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
       url: 'test.xml',
       success: function(response){
        console.debug(response);
        if (Ext.DomQuery.selectNode("/rootNode/name", response.responseXML)) {
            var name = Ext.DomQuery.selectValue("/rootNode/name",  response.responseXML);
            console.debug(name);
        } 

       },
       failure: function () { console.log('failure');}
    });
```